# KendoUI - Cascade Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui

I'm trying to do a simple code of taking Country -> State -> City. Can somebody tell me what's the issue in this case? The countries list load fine but after selecting the country, the states don't get loaded, nor is the event fired.

```
<script>
        var country = $('#inputCountry option:selected').val();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var countries = $("#country").kendoComboBox({
                autoBind:false,
                placeholder: "Select Country",
                dataTextField: "countryName",
                suggest:true,
                dataValueField: "geonameId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        read: {
                            url: "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON",
                            data: {
                                username: "kirobo"
                            },
                            cache:false,
                        }
                    },

                    schema : {
                        model: {
                            children: "geonames"
                        },
                        data: function(response) {
                            return response.geonames;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoComboBox");
            var state = $("#state").kendoComboBox({
                autoBind: false,
                suggest: true,
                cascadeFrom: "country",
                placeholder: "Select State",
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "geonameId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        read: {
                            url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON",
                            data: {
                                    username: "kirobo",
                                    geonameId: getCountry()
                                },
                            cache:false,

                        },
                        parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                            return {
                                username: "kirobo",
                                geonameId: getCountry()
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    cache:false,
                    schema : {
                        data: function(response) {
                            return response.geonames;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoComboBox");
            var cities = $("#city").kendoComboBox({
                suggest:true,
                autoBind: false,
                cascadeFrom: "state",
                placeholder: "Select City",
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "geonameId",
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        read: {
                            url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON",
                            data: {
                                username: "kirobo",
                                geonameId: getState()
                            },
                            cache:false,

                        },
                        parameterMap: function(data, type) {

                            return {
                                username: "kirobo",
                                geonameId: getState()
                            }
                        }

                    },

                    schema : {

                        data: function(response) {
                            return response.geonames;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoComboBox");
            function getCountry() {
                var combo = $("#country").data("kendoComboBox");
                return combo.value();
            }

            function getState() {
                var combo = $("#state").data("kendoComboBox");
                return combo.value();
            }
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second ComboBox definition for state, change:

```
cascadeFrom: "country"
```

to

```
cascadeFrom: "countries"
```

The 'cascadeFrom' gives the variable reference for the parent ComboBox rather than its JQuery selector: note that for your first ComboBox you have 'countries = $("#country")'. An alternative would be to change the first ComboBox to be:

```
var country = $("#country").kendoComboBox({
```

Your second ComboBox would then wire up correctly as it stands. Should be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the kendoComboBox object instead of using the combobox element in the cascade from field.

`var countries = $("#country").data(".kendoComboBox");
var state = $("#state").kendoComboBox({
                cascadeFrom: "countries"
});`

You should use this countries object in cascadeFrom field. That's it.